# Why TypeError even though it takes 2 arguments

Tags: python, runtime-error

What is wrong with this code? Even though I have passed arguments,
it throws a TypeError saying  `TypeError Computer() takes no arguments`.

```py
    class Computer:
        def __int__(self, cpu, ram):
            pass

    comp1 = Computer('i3', 16)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ymani\IdeaProjects\Python\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    comp1 = Computer('i3', 16)
TypeError: Computer() takes no arguments
`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 4):

simple typo.

`def __int__` should be `def __init__`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define cpu and ram in the class or you can define as global variables out of the class.
Like Below

```
def __init__(self, cpu, ram):
   cpu = self.cpu
   ram = self.ram
```

Then change `__int__` into `__init__`
It will work